# Get Record Flow Element when the filter includes a Formula Field

Tags: formula-field, screen-flow

Background: I have an object 'Request' that can have different SObjectTypes as its Parent. For eg. The Request can have an Opportunity as its Parent, OR it can have a Case as its Parent and so on.

- To achieve that I have created lookup fields on the Request object to the respective SObject Parents, lets say `ParentOpportunity__c` and `ParentCase__c`.
- I have also created a formula field `ParentId__c` on the Request object to dynamically determine the Parent Id:

  ```
  IF(ParentOpportunity__c != null, ParentOpportunity__c, 
     IF(ParentCase__c != null, ParentCase__c,''))
  ```
- I have a Screen Flow where I am using the Get Record Flow Element to query for Request records based on the ParentId.
- What I have observed is that if I use `ParentId__c = inputId`, I dont get a Record, but if I modify the criteria to use `ParentCase__c = inputId`, the record is found

Is there any limitation on the Get Record Flow Element if the filter includes a Formula Field ?

Comment: I'd look at whether the formula field on the Request__c resolves to 15 or 18 character ID and compare that to the value of `inputId`

Comment: Thanks @cropredy, the issue was indeed due to the formula field resolving to a 15 digit Id value and the recordPage passing in an 18 digit Id. I used caseSafeId() in the formula field to convert the formula to 18 digits and the get Record was able to find the record

Comment: I would like to mark your answer as the best answer, but unsure how to mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The likely cause of this is 15 versus 18 character Id values

- The formula resolves to a 15 character ID
- The flow input variable is an 18 character ID

Change the formula to use the `CASESAFEID()` function that will give you an 18 character Id